# How to read jsp file with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I'm trying to read my jsp file using spring-boot so i start the project and when i check my localhost it actually return the actual string "index" but not reading it as index.jsp (as jsp  file)

I've created Controller Class "HomeController" and implement a method  named homePage which will have @RequestMapping then it will return "index"

HomeController

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/showHome")
    public String homePage(){
     return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Spring Boot JSP Example</h1>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

project stucture
[image]

I've got "index" string in my browser was excpecting the jsp file to load
NB: when i replace @ResController with @Controller i get Whitelabel Error Page.

Comment: Do you set a  mapping  between `showHome` and `index`

Comment: what do u mean @VinuBibin ?

Comment: Your url is `showHome` and you are loading `index`, that what I understand from your question. So there should be a mapping between this, that the controller should understand

Comment: try the url localhost:port/showHome, it should return the page

Comment: i m returning "index" so later like application.properties will append .jsp

Comment: Your `requestMapping` is `/showHome`, so the url should be like that or some where you should map it.

Comment: i get it but should i provide it with the index.jsp path or how i m getting confused xD

Comment: No, either you can give `/` in request mapping or `/index`. Check this to know more about view resolver https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/

Comment: You are getting 404, because no mapping being configured with '/' or '/index'

Comment: how to configure it ???  
i've done what it says in  the link u provided me with

Comment: Your url should be map with requestmapping. In the example they hit http://localhost:8080/

Comment: yeah yeah i see but ican't think of a solution , i guess i gave u headache xD sorry

Comment: @VinuBibin. There is  no need for a mapping between /showHome and index. The path can be whatever and the jsp can be named whatever.

Comment: @AlanHay Yes I meant the url and the requestmapping that should link. He is trying with /index, but the mapping he given is /showHome

Comment: i've got this mesage in the log @VinuBibin
 No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

Comment: If you are running as proing boot app index should be available at {host}:{port}/showHome. You do not (and cannot if pages are under WEB-INF) access the jsp directly.

Comment: yeah but the prefix and the suffix will do the work here

Comment: *yeah but the prefix and the suffix will do the work here*. The prefix asnd suffix are used by the controller to locate the  file named "index" returned by the controller. **NO** resources  under /WEB-INF can be accessed by the browser. That is the whole point of putting them there.

Comment: so i should get them out  from WEB-INF ?

Comment: i know but i've done it but it didn't show the page i still have the 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this two line from application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and Delete **templates** folder from **resource** package.

Then add this class in your com.example.demo package.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.example"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
       registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
   }

   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }


}
```

In controller use:

```
 @Controller not @RestController
```

Like:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage() {
      return "index";
    }

}
```

Sample Blog site application (git source code ) with [Spring Boot and Hibernate](https://github.com/imrangthub/SpBootBlogSolutionUsingWithHibernate) you may get help from here.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change my pom.xml file dependecies where i import tomcat-embed and javax.servelet to

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use @Controller if you want to return jsp file. @RestController returns a string

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/showHome")
    public String homePage(){
     return "index";
    }
}
```

for configurations create WebConfig.java file and write in these:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.example.demo"
})

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Advise: see this link for more: [Hello Horld in Spring Boot](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page that's what i get when i change it to @Controller

Comment: also you need web.xml and servletContext.xml for configurations

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Sep 06 12:04:15 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: add web.xml and spring xml config file in your question

Comment: it is spring boot project i don't have them

Comment: The problem is not with the view resolver configuration, but invalid request mapping url or the path provided

Comment: what is path you request? write here. it must me localhost:8080/demo/showHome